# network - the role of m-buffer and ring buffer in networing domain

Tags: networking, linux-kernel

I have been searching around the answer to this but there is no clear answer I can find.

From freebsd man page, it describes mbuf as below:

```
An mbuf is a basic unit of memory management in the kernel IPC subsystem. Network packets and socket buffers are stored in mbufs.
A network packet may span multiple mbufs arranged into a mbuf chain (linked list), 
which allows adding or trimming network headers with little overhead.
An mbuf consists of a variable-sized header and a small internal buffer for data.
```

The ring buffer I can understand so far is that the NIC driver will pre-allocates the packet buffer ( ring buffer ) for the packet receiving process ( Rx in this case ).

I don't understand the role of these two different buffers in linux networking domain.

Please reply with your understanding to this.

Thanks

[*mbuf](https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/What_are_mbufs)

Answer (score 0):

You have the basics of the ring buffer down good.

As far as mbuf's are concerned, they're going to be similar to pbuf's if you've ever heard of them but it looks like they are a little more complex. They are just a simple structure that makes memory management easier (in this case for packet data). Unless you are dealing in kernel code, I wouldn't think you need to ever use mbuf's as the socket system should abstract it away from you in user-space.

Here is some more detailed info on mbuf's: https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?format=html&query=mbuf%289%29